# pythonic (3) way to map 2 dicts of lists into 1 list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

It's something like:

```
num_dict  = {'number':[1,2,3]}
lett_dict = {'letter': ['a','b','c']}
```

to become:

```
[{'number':1,'letter':'a'},{'number':2,'letter':'b'},{'number':3,'letter':'c'}]
```

**EDIT**

to put another way:

`{'number': [1, 2, 3], 'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c'],'symbol':['$','%','^']}`

to become

`[{'number':1,'letter':'a','symbol':'$'},{'number':2,'letter':'b','symbol':'%'},{'number':3,'letter':'c','symbol':'^'}]`

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way that I can think of is to use list comprehension:

```
[{'number':n, 'letter':l} for n,l in zip(list(num_dict.values())[0], list(lett_dict.values())[0])]
```

`zip` is used to return combined values from both in a loop, and `[0]` is used because when converting the dict values into a list it returned a list of list like so `[['a', 'b', 'c']]` so `[0]` was used to take only the inner list, rest of the part seems obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it

```
[{'number': n, 'letter': l} for n, l in zip(num_dict['number'], lett_dict['letter'])]
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation as to how your solution works, and maybe some timings? That will make it a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

after some headbanging:

```
>>> d = {'number': [1, 2, 3], 'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c'],'symbol':['$','%','^']}

>>> [dict(zip(d.keys(), v)) for v in zip(*(d[k] for k in d.keys()))]
```

result:

```
[{'number': 1, 'letter': 'a', 'symbol': '$'},
 {'number': 2, 'letter': 'b', 'symbol': '%'},
 {'number': 3, 'letter': 'c', 'symbol': '^'}]
```

Comment: This _might_ be the best answer, depending which of the two use-cases in the question is more important. One question: why `(d[k] for k in d.keys())` instead of `d.values()`?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I have no idea what "pythonic" means in practice.

You give two different examples of the same underlying problem. If you want a general purpose solution, then a helper function may be in order.

```py
from typing import *

def zip_dict(*dicts: Dict[str, Iterable[Any]],
        keys: Optional[Iterable[str]] = None
    ) -> Iterable[Dict[str, Any]]:
        use_keys = keys if keys is not None else list(map(lambda d: next(iter(d.keys())), dicts))
        indexed_dicts = {k: dicts[i][k] for i, k in enumerate(use_keys)}
        ret_length = len(dicts[0][use_keys[0]])
        return[
            dict((k, indexed_dicts[k][i]) for k in use_keys)
            for i in range(ret_length)
        ]

#test it out
from pprint import pprint

test_data = {'number': [1, 2, 3], 'letter': ['a', 'b', 'c'],'symbol':['$','%','^']}

first_test = zip_dict({'number': test_data['number']}, {'letter': test_data['letter']})
pprint(first_test)

second_test = zip_dict(test_data, test_data, test_data, keys = ['number', 'letter','symbol'])
pprint(second_test)
```

prints:

```
[{'letter': 'a', 'number': 1},
 {'letter': 'b', 'number': 2},
 {'letter': 'c', 'number': 3}]
[{'letter': 'a', 'number': 1, 'symbol': '$'},
 {'letter': 'b', 'number': 2, 'symbol': '%'},
 {'letter': 'c', 'number': 3, 'symbol': '^'}]
```

You'll notice that I've made no effort to prevent this function from throwing errors, or to specify how it should handle "weird" input. I don't know what your context is; if the input "should" always be correctly shaped, then this is probably fine.